# VBA Excel 2011 : Compile error : Method or data member not found - simple form

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in VBA and I tried to inspire me from https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html to make a simple userform and fill a Sheet.

Here the VBA code of userform (called Formulaire1) :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value1
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Value

' Set Fonction type
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
   Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Caption
Else
   Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox2.Caption
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload Me

EndSub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty ComboBox
ComboBox1.Clear

'Fill DinnerComboBox
ComboBox1.Value = "Monsieur"
With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Monsieur"
    .AddItem "Madame"
End With

'Empty NameTextBox
TextBox1.Value = ""

'Empty PhoneTextBox
TextBox2.Value = ""

'Set Elu by default
CheckBox1.Value = True
CheckBox2.Value = False

'Set Focus on NameTextBox
ComboBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

and below a capture of form :

[image: userForm]

I have inserted on Sheet a command button associated to a macro :

[image: Remplir formulaire button]

As you can see, I have added the 5 columns of data collected from the form.

Unfortunately, at the execution, I get the following message :

[image: Error compile]

with the indication (in yellow) into VBA source :

[image: Error compile]

I don't know where this error could come from, I hope this is not a typo error.

Comment: As an aside, later in code, you can simply write If CheckBox1 potentially. Without the = True. Not sure if you have to put .Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value1
```

with

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
```

This code just simply prints the data on one line, if you want it to print it on next line after first execution, add

> emptyRow = emptyRow + 1

after "Transfer Information", and inside a With statement referencing Sheet1.

After adding all these, your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Sheet1.Activate

With Sheet1
emptyRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1
    If .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
        emptyRow = emptyRow + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Value

        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
           .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Caption
        Else
           .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox2.Caption
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @JavyM : could you explicit the block "With statement referencing Sheet1" ? Is this : `With Me

emptyRow = emptyRow + 1

End With` at the end of `CommandButton1_Click()` function ?

Answer (score 1):

On the first line of `Transform information`section, replace `Value1` to just `Value`. This will take care of your runtime error.